# Line Chart data not showing

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to build a LineChart using chartjs, but I'm running through some issues with reading my data of the chart, the `console.log` function of dates and coin_value returns null for some reason even though the data is transferred from the server as it should.
any idea what is the problem??

Here is the web page with the console right now:

[image: web page + console]

and here is my code:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {Chart as chartjs, Title, Tooltip, LineElement, Legend, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement} from "chart.js";

chartjs.register(
  Title, Tooltip, LineElement, Legend, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement
)

function BitCoin() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [dates, setDates] = React.useState(null);
  const [coinValue, setCoinValue] = React.useState(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
      .then((res) => res.json()) 
      .then((data) => {

        const twoDimensionArr = data.message;
        setData(twoDimensionArr);               
        setDates(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[0]));    
        setCoinValue(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[1]));
   })
   .then(console.log(dates))
   .then(console.log(coinValue))
  }, []);

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
      label: "value of BTC in ILS",
      data: coinValue,
      backgroundColor: 'gold'
    }]
  }, [data])

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center", fontFamily:"Comic Sans MC", fontSize:"100"}}>
      THIS IS THE BitCoin PAGE

      <nav>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
      </nav>

      <nav>
        <Link to="/coins"> Coins </Link>
      </nav>

      <Line
      data = {chartData}
      />

    </div>
  )
}

export default BitCoin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usestate does not have a dependency array that automatically updates, so your `chartData` does never get updates. in your fetch you need to call `setChartData` already with the correct values.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {

      const twoDimensionArr = data.message;
      setData(twoDimensionArr);
      setDates(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[0]));
      setCoinValue(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[1]));
      setChartData({
        labels: twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[0]),
        datasets: [{
          label: "value of BTC in ILS",
          data: twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[1]),
          backgroundColor: 'gold'
        }]
      })
    })
    .then(console.log(dates))
    .then(console.log(coinValue))
}, []);
```

Comment: first off, thank you for your comment <3, but it apears I'm now getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'labels')